# Svelte Scroll Bind CSS Container Issue

Tags: css, svelte

I'm just getting familiar with working with binding. I have this file here: https://gist.github.com/JelaniThompson/74d062c5a28a18b75ca91cd44cd04d56

Does anyone know why `y` constantly returns `0` as opposed to the actual scroll position? I feel like this is more of a CSS issue than a Svelte issue but I could be mistaken.

When I did `window.addEventListener` instead, no events were being fired even on scroll with this HTML structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scrolling the scroller element but binding to `scrollY` on `window`. Because the window is not being scrolled, `scrollY` remains 0.

If you want to know how far the scroller element has been scrolled, you should use [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) instead. Svelte won't automatically bind this for you, so you'll need to set up the event listener yourself.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller" on:scroll={(e) => console.log(e.target.scrollTop)}>
    <!-- etc -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the scroll events fire at a high rate and you may need to [throttle it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event#Scroll_event_throttling) to prevent performance issues.